# Left Join multiple tables with ODBC Microsoft Access in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, odbc

I am joining multiple table with one common id which is Form_Tracking_ID , however i am getting an error while running the PHP page , below is my query code.

**Query Code**

```
$sql="SELECT reg.Form_Tracking_ID, reg.Date1, reg.Tool_File, reg.Tool_Cert, 
                    stat.Form_Tracking_ID, stat.Support_Image, stat.Update_Reason,
                    ext.Form_Tracking_ID, ext.From1, ext.To1, ext.CEF_ID,
                    Cext.Form_Tracking_ID, Cext.RequestImage, Cext.RequestDate, Cext.CEF_ID,
                    rep.Form_Tracking_ID, rep.From1, rep.Date2, rep.Report_No,
                    msa.Form_Tracking_ID, msa.MSAForm1, msa.Previous_Msa_Date, msa.Report_No,
                    dereg.Form_Tracking_ID, dereg.Dereg_Tool_Image, dereg.Dereg_Date1, dereg.Dereg_Reason1 
                    FROM registration1 reg
                    LEFT JOIN status1 stat ON reg.Form_Tracking_ID = stat.Form_Tracking_ID
                    LEFT JOIN extension1 ext ON reg.Form_Tracking_ID = ext.Form_Tracking_ID
                    LEFT JOIN extension_close1 Cext ON reg.Form_Tracking_ID = Cext.Form_Tracking_ID
                    LEFT JOIN report1 rep ON reg.Form_Tracking_ID = rep.Form_Tracking_ID
                    LEFT JOIN msa_report1 msa ON reg.Form_Tracking_ID = msa.Form_Tracking_ID
                    LEFT JOIN deregistration1 dereg ON reg.Form_Tracking_ID = dereg.Form_Tracking_ID WHERE reg.Form_Tracking_ID ='$emp'";
```

**The error that i get**

Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'reg.Form_Tracking_ID = stat.Form_Tracking_ID LEFT JOIN extension1 ext ON reg.Form_Tracking_ID = ext.Form_Tracking_ID LEFT JOIN extension_close1 Cext ON reg.Form_Tracking_ID = Cext.Form_Tracking_ID '., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\Calibration_Form\tooldetailTest.php on line 223

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: odbc_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($statement) must be of type resource, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Calibration_Form\tooldetailTest.php:224 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Calibration_Form\tooldetailTest.php(224): odbc_fetch_array(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Calibration_Form\tooldetailTest.php on line 224

Comment: If you join one by one, it will help you to find the error. Since I can't see your tables, I can't guess your issue. But, I don't see any syntax error.

Comment: @Hani why is it showing syntax error then haha.

Comment: Access will complain due to lack of parentheses. Why don't you use Access query builder to construct the SQL then copy/paste it into code?